# Call to a member function find() on a non-object with extended model

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an "Admin" model which extends another model "User" which extends the "AppModel".

I have a controller "ApisController" in which I am trying to query the data from the admins table.

So I'm doing something like this:

```
$admins = $this->Admin->find('all');
```

But when I do that, I get the following error message:

```
Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: /home/farhan/www/core/app/Controller/ApisController.php   
Line: 9
```

If I try to do the same thing in a controller "AdminsController", everything works fine. So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm new to cake, so I understand if this is a simple error.

Comment: How do you load the model? That is your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have ApisController and want to use an "Admin" model (which clearly is not the singular form from "Apis" - it would probably be Api), you need to manually declare your used model:

```
public $uses = array('Admin');
```

Then the controller has the "Admin" model available as primary one.

[Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller%3a%3a%24uses)

Default is that cake tries to find the right one based on inflection:

```
PostsController => Post model
(plural => singular)
```

Comment: This worked! I forgot to load the model. So I assume you don't have to load the model if the name of the controller is the same as the model? Because it was working fine without this in my controller called "AdminController".

Comment: You should know that the controller uses its primary model by default - and that the naming convention is plural AdminsController, singular Admin model. If you declare "admin" as uninflicted, you would have both singular. That is not the default, though.